# How to give Prayaschitta Arghya?

Tags: rituals, sandhyavandanam

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/time-to-perform-sandhyavandanam/14260#14260) says if anybody missed to perform Sandhyavandanam within prescribed time, Prayaschitta Arghya should be given.

My question is how to give Prayaschitta Arghya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This arghyam is given when we miss performing a sandhyavandanam i.e. before the sunrise in the morning, before the sun gets overhead in the evening and before the sunset in the evening. If we perform within the prescribed time, then it is not needed.

We have to do praNaayaama, say sankalpam that we are giving a prayaschitta arghya. Then we have to give the arghya just like we do it before*. This is called *Kālātīta prāyaścitta arghyaṃ*.

*According to some sampradays, the arghyam offered [is thrice](http://www.samskaaram.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=34:vadakalai&catid=3&lang=en) at all the parts of the day. Whereas, in [some other](http://tamilbrahmins.ucoz.org/sandyavandanam_english.pdf) , it is once in the morning, twice in the noon and thrice in the evening. This change is due to the shakshas and Grihya sutras they follow.

Comment: there is a slight difference in the gayatri mantra vyahruthis in beginning and end when doing prayaschitta arghyam vs regular arghyam

Comment: the saying in tamil is 'kaanamal, konaamal, kandu' - meaning without seeing sun (before sunrise), sun not slanted (at noon), seeing sun (before sunset)

Answer (score 0):

Ajay, you should have learned Sandhya Vandana from your father or acharya or local matam or ashram, soon after upanayanam was done. If you have forgotten the mantras, full details of sandhya vandana here (Sanskrit & Tamil.. also english)

http://srivaishnavam.com/stotras/prata_sandhya.htm

But if none has taught you, do not self-learn.. first learn from elder, then use above as reference to refresh memory.

Comment: @Ajay, madhyanikam can be done in sangava kala (8.24-10.48) as a workardound instead of madhyanika kala (10.48-1.12).. nowadays when everything is difficult, as long as u do it at some time, it's better than not doing. also, the arghyam after punar-prokshanam is regular arghyam (3 times). after that, pranayanam, sankalpam & turyia-arghya-pradanam is for prayaschittam.

Comment: So pradha Sandhya?

Comment: @Ajay, ideal pratah sandhya time is brahma muhurtham (4.24-6) for without prayaschitta-arghyam, or pratah kala (6-8.24) for with prayaschitta-arghyam. the saying is 'kaanamal, konaamal, kandu' - meaning without seeing sun (before sunrise), sun not slanted (at noon), seeing sun (before sunset).

Comment: Is bathing required to do morning Sandhya vandanam?

Comment: @Ajay, Absolutely. only exception is when you cannot find water, or you're bed-sick.

Comment: In which direction should we face while doing Harihara Vandanam? One book says west and other says north. What is correct?

Comment: @Ajay, idk what harihara vandanam is. Check with your elders. Pratah sandhya arghyam is facing east. Madhyanikam is facing north. Sayam arghyam is facing west.

Comment: Today I failed to do pratha sandhyavandam as I woke up only at nine due to fever. What should I do?

Comment: @Parikshitha, do extra prashanam (suryascha), argyam, prayaschitta-argyam, keshavadi tarpanam & gayatri japam when doing the next sandhya (madhyanikam or sayam) along with those same items (e.g. instead of 3 argyam do 6, instead of 10 gj, do 20 gj). Or do the same during next prathas when you feel better.